# How can I manipulate the resulting Import-Package statement of a OsgiManifest in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, osgi, manifest

I'd like to filter out an entry of `Import-Package` instruction, because it's an sun native package.

Currently the resulting Manifest reads

```
Import-Package: javax.net.ssl,javax.security.auth.kerberos,org.jivesof
 tware.smack;version="[4.1,5)",org.jivesoftware.smack.initializer;vers
 ion="[4.1,5)",org.jivesoftware.smack.util.stringencoder;version="[4.1
 ,5)",sun.security.util
```

But, I'd like to remove `sun.security.util`, so that it becomes

```
Import-Package: javax.net.ssl,javax.security.auth.kerberos,org.jivesof
 tware.smack;version="[4.1,5)",org.jivesoftware.smack.initializer;vers
 ion="[4.1,5)",org.jivesoftware.smack.util.stringencoder;version="[4.1
 ,5)"
```

I've thought that it should be possible with something like

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    def importPackages = ((OsgiManifest) project.jar.manifest).instructionValue('Import-Packages')
    def filteredImportPackages = importPackages.findAll { it != 'sun.security.util' }
    ((OsgiManifest) project.jar.manifest).instructionReplace('Import-Packages', filteredImportPackages)
}
```

But this causes an ClassCastException:

```
Cannot cast object 'org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest@136bec49' with class 'org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest' to class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.osgi.OsgiManifest'
```

**How can I manipulate the (Osgi)Manifest after it has been configured by gradle?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to remove the `sun.security.util` package just by using bnd instructions like this:

```
jar {
    manifest { // the manifest of the default jar is of type OsgiManifest
        instruction 'Import-Package', '!sun.security.*, *'
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, great, didn't knew that one can do the stuff from http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Format